# Auto Rotate not working after setRequestedOrientation

Tags: android, autorotate

I have an Activity with auto-rotate is allowed:

```
<activity
            android:name="com.xxx.ui.browse.exercise.ExerciseActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.XXX.Light" />
```

The auto-rotate works perfectly. But now I want to change programmaticaly, in some specific cases, the screen orientation. So I did that:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

It works great too. BUT now the auto-rotate doesn't work...

I tried to call after the setRequestedOrientation, but not effect:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
```

Could you help me guys?

Comment: Interesting, same feature/system I use in app for years.
The only difference I see in defined `android:configChanges="orientation"` parameter, which I do not use for activities. Try to remove it just for test, if this helps.

Comment: @MenionAsamm it doesn't work properly